# c# GUI layout manager

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

Which GUI layout manager is recommend these days?

I saw SmartLayouts (looked nice to work with) and the devexpress extralayout control, but not quit sure about this one.

Are there other players on the marked? 
What experience do you all have with these controls?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've used Actipro's Dock Manager for years.  It's really nice, and their support is great.

Answer (score 1):

Devexpress is the best. I use it in my work, the license is expensive but is really good.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress layout manager works for us quite well so i definitely suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

On the Open Source side, there is [Dock Panel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite). I have no personal experience with it but it has good press.

More interesting suggestions in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186115).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find the devexpress one very slow
I love devexpress but I'm not sure about this control.
Try a form with lots of controls. You'll notice everything getting slower.
Also the designer takes a big hit!